# MuseScore 3 Prevent Grouping (Beaming) Notes

Tags: musescore, beaming

I'm trying to write a Sheet on MuseScore 3.
[image: "El Coro Celestial", by A.G. Horst]

[image: MuseScore transcription of "El Coro Celestial"]

The Question is:
As you can see in the original Sheet the notes aren't grouped...

**How can I prevent automatic grouping of the notes?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Select the entire area you want unbeamed.
2. In the "Beam Properties" palette, select the unbeamed eighth-note.

---

#### Starting score

[image: Example score with beamed notes]

#### Select the region to unbeam

[image: Example score with selected region]

#### On the "Beam Properties" palette, click the "No beam" icon

[image: Beam Properties palette with No Beam icon highlighted]

#### End result

[image: Example score with selected region unbeamed]

Comment: If you find yourself doing this a lot, you can also bind it to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 8):

> How prevent Grouping automatically notes?

Click on "time signatures" in palettes, select "more" and "create time signature". This opens a window where you can select how the notes should be grouped. Edit grouping and click "Add". Then close the window and apply your newly created time signature.

Comment: Of all the places it would never have occurred to me to look ....

Comment: @Aaron Non intuitive indeed. But if you go through this, this way provides automatic beaming both for existing and newly written notes. Overall not bad for a free program.

Comment: @Aaron In hindsight it does make sense though because the time signature determines the grouping you usually want.

Comment: @Nobody you're right! Especially if you want to have a consistent non-standard grouping.